# What is the error in this part of the code?

Tags: c, data-structures, tree

```
typedef struct tree_node
{
    int data;
    struct tree_node *left;
    struct tree_node *right;
}node;

node* newnode(int data)
{
    node *node=(node*)(malloc(sizeof(struct tree_node)));
    node->data=data;
    node->left=NULL;
    node->right=NULL;

    return(node);
}
```

The code is showing error in this part. What is the error? Why is it not compiling?
EDIT: The error shown is error: expected primary-expression before ')' token. However if I change the code to

```
node* newnode(int data)
{
    node *node1=(node*)(malloc(sizeof(struct tree_node)));
    node1->data=data;
    node1->left=NULL;
    node1->right=NULL;

    return(node1);
}
```

it works perfectly. What is the reason for this?

Comment: what error? Please give us more information.

Comment: Could you tell us what error you're getting and where?

Comment: I think `node *node=(node*)(malloc(sizeof(struct tree_node)));` causing the error! change `*node` to `*node1`- `node *node1=(node*)(malloc(sizeof(struct tree_node)));`

Comment: Please don't tag questions as both C and C++ unless your question is actually about both C and C++. Which is it? It looks like you've written it to be used by a C++ compiler. Is that correct? If so, please remove the C tag. If not, please remove the C++ tag. Either language has correct answers that don't apply to the other language.

Comment: Sorry..noob user.. I edited the question

Answer (score 3):

You use *node* as a typename, but it's a variable.
Change it to:

```
typedef struct tree_node
{
    int data;
    struct tree_node *left;
    struct tree_node *right;
};

tree_node* newnode(int data)
{
    tree_node *node=(tree_node*)(malloc(sizeof(struct tree_node)));
    node->data=data;
    node->left=NULL;
    node->right=NULL;

    return(node);
}
```

and next time please share the compiler error too, don't expect us to find it out...

Comment: `typedef struct tree_node {` .. `};` is invalid . Some common compilers accept it and appear to silently ignore the `typedef` keyword.

Comment: also, [don't cast malloc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: @MattMcNabb That's actually valid IIRC, surprisingly enough, simply because the standard (possibly accidentally) fails to prohibit it. But the `typedef` keyword is indeed useless there. And since the question is now properly tagged as C, `(tree_node*)` needs to be `(struct tree_node*)`, or `typedef struct tree_node { ... } tree_node;` is required.

Comment: @hvd hmm, C11 6.7.8/3 seems to imply that there must be an identifier but it is not very clear. Is there another SO question on this topic already?

Comment: @MattMcNabb I'm assuming 6.7.8 is Type definitions? (That's 6.7.7 in C99.) It doesn't prohibit this; it states the behaviour for each declarator, and doesn't treat "no declarators" as a special case, so specifies that `typedef` be ignored. The constraint in 6.7/2 ("A declaration shall declare at least a declarator (other than the parameters of a function or the members of a structure or union), a tag, or the members of an enumeration.") is what prohibits `typedef int;`, but in this case, there is a tag, so the constraint is not violated. I have no link to other questions on this, sorry.